# importing a single csv file to mysql database(multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, cron, crm, vtiger

I’m using vtiger crm. I have a csv file which contains list of contacts. I want to import the csv file to vtiger database in every 30 minutes. The problem is in the csv file, a single row contains data for three tables in the same database. Like name will go to contactdetails, company name will go to accounts and all the custom fields go to contactcf table.

Is there any way I can import the csv files to mysql database?

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you looked into using the webservices?